# ROS - check if a node is still alive

Tags: communication, nodes, message, ros

I'm implementing a control node for a device with four wheels. So far I have the following nodes:

```
TALKER:
--Publishes messages for movement of vehicle

LISTENER:
--Listens to messages for movement of vehicle and controls vehicle directly
```

The communication between these two works and my only problem is what to do if either one shuts down in order to prevent uncontrolled movement of the vehicle. `ros::isShuttingDown()` call in the LISTENER so it detects when it's about to be killed.

However, if the TALKER is shut down the LISTENER keeps moving the vehicle according to the last message received from TALKER. First I tried to use `ros::isShuttingDown()` in TALKER as well in order to send a final "stop" message to LISTENER, but it seems that once the node is shutting down, no communication is possible.

Therefore I'm looking for a way to check inside LISTENER if the node TALKER is still alive (or if new messages are still being received).

Anyone an idea on how to see if a node (in this case TALKER) is still alive? Or is there an easy method for detecting how long it has been since the last ROS message was received?

Comment: It's fun coming back to an old question from when I was just starting out on my robotics journey.

For anyone stumbling upon this question: The correct answer here would be to rewrite the LISTENER such that it detects stale messages and stops moving the vehicle after messages from the TALKER stopped coming in for X amount of seconds. Nodes are independent programs and should be structured accordingly .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [bond](http://wiki.ros.org/bond) package. I believe it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Found another interesting and already built-in way with including "ros/network.h":

```
// master.h:
....

/**
* \brief Retreives the currently-known list of nodes from the master
*/
ROSCPP_DECL bool getNodes(V_string& nodes);

....
```

However, I didnt figure out how to use it from within another cpp file...

Comment: I found this very helpful! I used this in testing, that I could run a launch file several times, all under different namespaces, testing different configuration settings - when one node died, all nodes in that namespace died. To do this, I made a master node that called `ros::master::getNodes(std::vector<std::string>)`, ran at a low frequency, checked if any nodes disappeared/died, then used that namespace to kill any other node in its list with that same namespace. It's quite scalable, and doesn't require any changes to existing nodes, just launch files.

Comment: To kill a node, I used the (c)stdlib `system()`: `system(("rosnode kill " + node_name_to_kill).c_str());` To kill the program, when only the master node (and the ignored rosout node) are left (or just kill it all, for any reason), `system("killall -2 rosmaster")`, where -2 is used for SIGINT, the clean/nice way to shutdown nodes. This can be escalated to -15 for SIGTERM, which is still functional.

Comment: @JWCS Thanks for your comment. However, ROS is a C++ library. And having to resort to system calls seems like a really wrong approach since there must be library functions to do directly what's needed without going through the commandline. I really hope there is a better way than what you describe. But I have not been following recent ROS development.

Comment: This is pretty much the supported way, rosnode kill sends a SIGINT. ROS designed ros::shutdown to use SIGINT; calling the internal (and overridable) shutdown handler. Even if it did more, calling rosnode kill is the most future-proof method: it will always soft-quit. But remember, ROS targets a linux platform at its core, which provides too-attractively powerful system interoperability through c, hence SIGINT. & c++ at its core is just a c extension. I really like how we can get other nodes through ros::network, but having now examined all the headers, I haven't found a better way to kill : /

Comment: Or, like, if I could, I'd just add roslaunch xml attributes `required="true"` or `respawn="true"` to `<node>` to do what the OP wants. Didn't apply to my case, but a solid 90% could just be handled by making it all shutdown in case of a crash, not just selectively shutting down as I commented. [(<node> attributes)](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes)