# ROS2 - check if a node is still alive

Tags: c++, nodes, communication, ros2

This question is similar to [ROS - check if a node is still alive (@Potaito)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982406/ros-check-if-a-node-is-still-alive?rq=1), but now this question is for ROS 2 (Foxy to be precise).

To explain my problem in short. I'm trying to check if a client of another publisher node is still alive. rclcpp_lifecycle could be an interesting way of tackling this problem, but it is made for when nodes 'properly' shutdown or change state. I am seeking for a robuster way, e.g. in case a node just crashes. So if when a node crashes, the publisher knows, and can, for example, stop publishing.

I have found that the [bondcpp](http://wiki.ros.org/bondcpp) library, which is updated to ROS 2, does not function properly. 
Also, just checking via the function `std::vector<std::string> rclcpp::Node::get_node_names() const` if the node still is alive can work, but is just too slow. It takes a while before a dead node gets removed from the node list (~10-20sec).
That is why I am seeking an alternative.

Is there any other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This capability doesn't exist *natively* in the ROS2 stack. You need some sort of watchdog, and you can definitely implement your own solution without too much work.

[bondcpp](https://github.com/ros/bond_core/tree/ros2) *should* work for this. An example project that uses bond pervasively is [Nav2](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2).

However, `bondcpp` can also incur a lot of network overhead.

You may also look at implementing your own "heartbeat" topic, using "Manual by topic" Liveliness QoS, and then asserting liveliness inside the alive node on a timer. Then have watchers subscribe to the ["liveliness lost" QoS event](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/About-Quality-of-Service-Settings.html#qos-events) to perform actions if the other node dies or locks up.

You also may want to take a look at [software_watchdogs](https://github.com/ros-safety/software_watchdogs)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
You can use [the rclcpp method get_subscriptions_info_by_topic](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/c15eb1eaac2e05b507164a557cda5ff11d49c813/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node.hpp#L1046-L1070) and check for any subscriber on a specific topic. This is a reliable, robust native way to achieve what you want.

**Solution 2:**
Another maybe more versatile (?) but dirty approach is to check the process id of the node.

C++ not ROS2 specific code to retrieve a PID is:

```
#include <unistd.h>  
std::cout << "pid= " << getpid() << std::endl;
```

You can then send the PID to the node that has to check if it exist. To do so you can send a kill(0) call to the process and check the return value. By using a callback timer you can check synchronously. Notice however that your process could die and something else could take its process id.

```
#include <signal.h>
int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);
```